# LIBUSB_ERROR_BUSY [-6] Sending a basic packet with Python 3.9 using LibUSB1

Tags: python-3.x, handle

I am developing some software in python 3.9 and I am at the point where I have a device connected to my USB port and would like to send a basic packet to test the interface before I proceed. I am using this example to try and get my interface to work. I am not bothered about speed or byte count. I would like to see any response on the interface (But on reflection Im wondering if usb speed could be the issue):

```
    import usb1
    import usb.util
    import os
    import sys
    import libusb
    import usb.core
    from usb import util
    import math

    dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x11ac,idProduct=0x317d)

    with usb1.USBContext() as context:
        handle=context.openByVendorIDAndProductID(
            0x11ac,
            0x317d,)
        handle.claimInterface(0)
        handle.setInterface(0)

   data = bytearray(b"\\xf0\\x0f"* (int(math.ceil(0xb5db91/4.0))))
   handle.controlWrite(0x40, 0xb0, 0xb5A6, 0xdb91, b"")
   handle.bulkWrite(2,data,timeout=5000)
```

`

https://github.com/vpelletier/python-libusb1/issues/21

I have had a look in various forums  for several days and cannot seem to get an answer that works. Here is the trace: Its worth noting that from time to time, this py file does run without error but does nothing, and I see no traffic traveling to the USB interface.

Can someone please help me configure a working example of how to send a packet to the interface? I have tried various things like detaching the kernel, setting configuration, etc.

For 4 days I have struggled with libusb01 & 10, after discovering libusb1, I have changed my wrapper and got a lot more success

I also see a lot of examples in forums like this one, and I always get the same response. Also Im curious as to where it appears that 0x40 is the endpoint(out)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jbgilbert/Desktop/Packets/Backend_replace.py", line 16, in <module>
    handle.claimInterface(0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/usb1/__init__.py", line 1213, in claimInterface
    libusb1.libusb_claim_interface(self.__handle, interface),
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/usb1/__init__.py", line 133, in mayRaiseUSBError
    __raiseUSBError(value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/usb1/__init__.py", line 125, in raiseUSBError
    raise __STATUS_TO_EXCEPTION_DICT.get(value, __USBError)(value)
usb1.USBErrorBusy: LIBUSB_ERROR_BUSY [-6]
```

Comment: `h` is not defined. How is it initialized?

Comment: Hey Manuel, sorry it was a bit late in the evening, and I must have reversed some changes I made to the script, I shall update the post with the following

data = bytearray(b"\\xf0\\x0f"* (int(math.ceil(0xb5db91/4.0))))
   handle.controlWrite(0x40, 0xb0, 0xb5A6, 0xdb91, b"")
   handle.bulkWrite(2,data,timeout=5000)

Comment: Running lsmod, I notice that all 6 devices (0 to 5) are being used by something, I think this may perhaps be my problem

Answer (score 0):

My device is a laptop, using lsmod reveals all devices linked to that particular end point, in this case because if the presence of a webcam I was unable to write to an available end point. Despite disabling the driver I had no avail and had to try to code on a machine that had less onboard accessories that proved more successful